# Hadoop is not starting any datanode

Tags: hadoop

I've configured hadoop-2.2.0 on Ubuntu/linux but when I tried to run it via `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn` it gave me this error:

```
Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where  applicable
```

And when I go to `localhost:50070/nn_browsedfscontent.jsp` then it gives me the following error:

```
Can't browse the DFS since there are no live nodes available to redirect to.
```

So I followed this [link](http://dataheads.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/hadoop-2-setup-on-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04-part-3/comment-page-1/) to build hadoop from source but the problem still persists. Help needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode` and then `hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode` and check your browser at `localhost:50070`

Comment: hadoop-daemon.sh command has been deprecated and it also doesn't start anything. And when I do the same with 'yarn start tasktracker' then it gives me error that it is unable to load class tracker... I'm still stuck